# Фильтр для проверки фото на цензуру

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, поиск-библиотек, поиск-api

Разрабатываю подобие социальной сети. Как пристроить к приложению (создать/найти) фильтр для проверки фото на цензуру. Чтобы люди не загружали на аватар условно фото половых органов и т.д.

Comment: Скорее всего никак. Все сервисы, что мне известны, пропускают некоторые половые органы.

Comment: Надеюсь ещё будут более полезные комментарии

Comment: Не будут, потому что скорее всего никак. Для каждого фильтра я найду неприличную картинку, которую этот фильтр пропустит.

Comment: Так я же не предлагаю все неприличные картинки предотвратить. Понятное дело, будут выбросы. Но есть же решение предотвратить большую часть картинок с порнографией

Comment: Лично я не вижу в этом смысла. Если народ захочет запостить порнографию — он её запостит. Только ручная модерация.

Comment: Если вас интересуют неработающие решения, то есть к примеру https://isitnude.com/ или http://isitporn.com/ или можно свою нейросеть натренировать